# Maxima and Minima, Critical value

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

We have a function: $f(x,y)= xy-x$
defined on the set 
$$D = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : 0 ≤ y ≤ 2-x^2\}.$$

I have found the critical point to be $(0,1)$, which I'm not sure is true. 
But I also have to find the biggest and smallest value that the function has in the set $D$.

I have defined the following, but can't come further:

$$D_1 = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x = 0, 0 ≤ y ≤ 2\}$$
$$D_2 = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: y = 0, -\sqrt{2}≤ x ≤ \sqrt{2}\}$$
$$D_3 = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: y = 2-x^2, -\sqrt{2}≤ x ≤ \sqrt{2}\}$$

And then I'm supposed to find the values from those definitions, but I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve $D_1$ is not part of the boundary of $D$.  If you change the definition of $D_3$ to
$$
    D_3 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \color{blue}{-\sqrt{2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{2}},\ y=2-x^2\}
$$
Then $D_2$ and $D_3$ form the boundary of $D$.

Since $D$ is closed and bounded, the global max and min exist.  Either they occur in the interior of $D$, or on the boundary of $D$.  You have already found the one critical point in the interior of $D$.  To find critical points on the boundary, look at the functions
\begin{align*}
    g_1(x) &= f(x,0) & - \sqrt{2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{2} \\
    g_2(x) &= f(x,2-x^2) & - \sqrt{2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{2} \\
\end{align*}
These you can analyze with single-variable calculus techniques.

Comment: Okay, would it be correct to say that the largest value in D for the function is sqrt(2) in both D2 and D3, and that the smallest value is -sqrt(2) in both D2 and D3?